# Node.js error including js file - file cannot be found

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm running a node.js server. In the node I require and run the module by using

```
var h = require('h.js');
h.hello();
```

This prints Hello World to the console. However, I want to be able to run the code from h.js from a page(entrypage.html) in my browser as well. I try to import it by

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/h.js"></script>
```

However, this gives a 404 error when run on localhost.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/node_modules/h.js
```

How do I get access to this javascript file on the HTML page?

My file structure has a root with html/, js/, node_modules/ and server.js. The HTML page is inside html/, the js file in node_modules/

EDIT: I'm using the MEAN stack for this - MongoDB, Express.js, Angular.js and Node.js.

Comment: I agree with @rgvassar you can/should not server node_modules with nodejs. You probably want to create an alias for your nodejs in your http server config. With nginx for example, create a `/` route redirecting to your `localhost:3333` (where `3333` is your nodejs application) and a `/public/` one serving all files found in /node_modules directory for example

Comment: Assuming that your server can serve JS files, the link to your file from the browser should be `src="node_modules/h.js"` (no leading slash). I've just tested this with the sig_pad code you linked to. [Here's the server (non-Express) code I used](https://jsfiddle.net/ufhqh520/).

Comment: Andy, linking the files like you suggested does not seem to work for me. Also your jsfiddle is missing an html file and the signature_pad.js file include. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to serve the file using `express.static` (Example:  `app.use('/node_modules/', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));`), but I highly advise against serving node_modules and backend-specific files in the frontend!

Comment: This works, thank you! I'm a bit confused by Thomas' /public/ suggestion up above. Should I put my public modules in a /public/ directory and the rest in node_modules/? Or is there some way to link only some of the node_modules file to the frontend?

Comment: What Chris said. However, if you decide to go with the solution of exposing your node_modules folder via http as proposed, you will need to adjust your frontend to point to the file, since express will make the whole node_modules folder available under root (/), so the href would be "/h.js" and not "node_modules/h.js"

Comment: @WarSame If you want to use your node_modules in the frontend as well, best practice would be to use a bundler like browserify or webpack.

Comment: No need in this case because the module uses the UMD spec which means it exports as CommonJS, AMD, or browser depending on the environment.

Answer (score 1):

first define path for your static resource which is your CSS,JS,Images etc.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));
```

then in  html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="h.js"></script>
```

NOTE :
*Try to avoid to use **node_modules** folder for source path of your static resources*

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, I take it that you want to run the code in the browser just like running code in the node.js environment using `require` to include packages like h.js from npm.

If that's what you want to do I would recommend using a tool like browserify or webpack which collects your code and puts it into a file which can then be used in a web browser.

Comment: Yes, I want to run the code in my browser. To give you a full idea of my problem: I am trying to use [this signature pad file](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) to have signature pads in my web form. However, to do so I need to include the source .js file. Therefore, I thought the best way was to include the .js file with a regular <script> tag. Am I wrong?